# Glassfish-4 jersey REST application resource not found

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey

I am using Glassfish 4 and I have created a simple web application with a simple REST web service. 
Everything was working fine, until I tried to create a new glassfish installation. When I finish the new installation, I deploy the war and it gets successfully deployed without any errors on the glassfish log. After the deploy, when I launch the web app from the url that the admin console provides:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyRESTWebApp_war/
```

I get a status 404 not found error...

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyRESTWebApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>my.package.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyRESTWebApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I also have configured a class extending Application with a @Path annotation:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyRESTWebAppApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        return getResourceClasses();
    }

    private Set<Class<?>> getResourceClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        resources.add(Example.class);
        return resources;
    }
}
```

I can not remember what configurations I did on my previous glassfish installation, this is very frustrating...

I also get a 404 error when I try to test the example helloworld Rest service:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyRESTWebApp_war/rest/helloworld
```

Comment: Can you check the logs in glassfish server and paste the same

Comment: There is nothing on the log file when I hit the links or when I deploy the war...

Comment: Can you deploy the same in tomcat and get the catalina.log and localhost.log ?

Comment: Your `Application` sublcass is redundant. You can completely get rid of it. The web.xml configuration is enough to configure the app.

Comment: I got rid of the Application class, but nothing is changed ...

Comment: Is the name of your app (war file) really `MyRESTWebApp_war` or is it just `MyRESTWebApp`?

Comment: The name of the generated war is indeed MyRESTWebApp_war

Comment: Other than than that what you've provided looks fine. The problem is with something we _can't_ see.

Comment: Could this be something in glassfish's configuration?

Comment: Oh and BTW, `@Path("/rest")` should be `@ApplicationPath("/rest")`. But like I said the class is not needed, as your web.xml looks fine. But you can try to correct the annotation to see what happens. If it doesn't work, I would check to see if the app is actually deployed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

what about url http://localhost:8080/MyRESTWebApp_war/rest/rest/ ?

Your rest apis url start from /rest/* and your resource class url also start from /rest.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just access it with http://localhost:8080/rest/ ?
And what does your `Example.class` look like ?

**UPDATE**

The reason you can't access this url is pretty simple I think, you service has been well deployed on http://localhost:8080/MyRESTWebApp_war/rest/ and the fact you reached a 404 response on it is because you don't have a GET method implemented on that path. Try to create a resource such as this :

```
@Path("/")
class RootResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(){
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few glassfish restarts my rest services are working as expected.

I am still getting a 404 error when I access:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyRESTWebApp_war/
```

But when I click on the full RESTful service link:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyRESTWebApp_war/rest/helloworld
```

I am getting the expected response...

I still haven't figured out what I was doing wrong, this took me almost all day to figure out... Thank you all for your time and your suggestions!